# Cannot set header after they are send to client error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a requirement where I have to authorise user from multiple servers. Based on the response returned from all the servers, I want to return the value to the UI accrodingly. However, I am getting cannot set header error. Here is my code:

server.js

```
app.post('/auth/:data', function (req, res) {
var data1 = req.params.data;   
//connect to ldap server
ldapConnect.checkLDAPUser(data1, function(responseFromLdap){ 
 if(responseFromLdap!="invalidCredentials")
  {
    server2Connect.checkUser(responseFromLdap.uid,function(responseFromServer2)
      {         
        if(responseFromServer2=="success")
        {
           //connect to elastic search
           ESclient.getUserRolesfromES(responseFromLdap.uid,function(responseRolesFromES)
           {

                var rolesArr=responseRolesFromES.split(',')
            rolesArr.forEach(element => {
              ESclient.getScreensForRoles(element,function(resScreenFromES){

                  var screenArr=resScreenFromES.split(',');

                  screenArr.forEach(screen => {

                    if (!(screenArrFinal.includes(screen)))
                    {
                      screenArrFinal.push(screen);                          
                    }

                  });
                  if(rolesArr[rolesArr.length-1] === element){
                  console.log(screenArrFinal)
                  res.send(screenArrFinal)
                  }
           });

        }
      }
  }
```

I ideally want to return the screenArrFinal to UI so I that display the user screens based on his roles.But I am getting an error at res.send(). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: getScreensForRoles probably tries to send response multiple times. can you send response after this loop is finished?

Comment: If I send after loop finishes, the screenArrFinal is empty.

Comment: Yes of course, you can define a variable outside of the scope, then add the results to that variable, so you access and send it.

Comment: @MücahidErenler Sorry I din quite understand.. could you kindly explain?

Comment: @MücahidErenler I have initialised screenArrFinal as a global variable and hence thought it will have the value as and when it changes.

Comment: ok i missed that some of the calls are suppose to be sync. can you change the end point to `async function` and await for the calls you made. i understand both `ldapConnect` `checkUser` and `getUserRolesfromES` needs to be waited before sending response.